# Manually generating x-gwt-rpc from Python

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I want to access a GWT service from a Python script, so I want to generate a x-gwt-rpc request manually. Can't seem to find any info on the format of a GWT RPC call, since everybody does it from Java (so the call is generated by the framework). Where can I find some detailed documentation about this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it is a trivial task to do that, but because gwt is opensource i would say that the source-code is a pretty good documentation for how it works, if you know java that is.

[Gwt source](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/checkout)

Comment: I was hoping for a more optimistic answer, but judging by the lack of interest in answering this question, this is probably the only way to go. It was not a priority until now, but I'll have to dig into it soon. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same problem as you and I think I solved it rather easily.
Though I haven't figured out how to catch the response properly, I managed to get the response and successfully send the request. Here is what I did:

```
import requests 
url  = 'yours url'
header = {'Accept':'*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
         etc...
        }
cookie = {cookies if needed
}

data_g = 'this would be request payload u can see in F12 of browser '# u just copy it and paste it, !!!like a string (UTF-8 chars)
t = requests.post(url, headers=header, data = data_g, cookies = cookie)
print vars(t).keys()
#line above will print all variables of t
print t
```

Also these are some good links you should check out:

https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit?hl=de&forcehl=1