# Send HTTP request with GWT-RPC call via Python

Tags: python, gwt, gwt-rpc

I need to initiate an action on server via sending the HTTP request with GWT-RPC call in body section. I'm completely new in GWT subject so please forgive my lack of knowledge. In Java I was able to perform this action via sending HTTP POST request with proper headers and GWT-RPC in body so I tried to do the same in Python with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.
Unfortunately, when sending GWT-RPC call I got response:

```
//EX[2,1,["com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException/3936916533","This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting version between 5 and 7 )"],0,7]
```

I read few topics:

- [Manually generating x-gwt-rpc from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193446/manually-generating-x-gwt-rpc-from-python),
- [com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134209/com-google-gwt-user-client-rpc-incompatibleremoteserviceexception)

and as I understood there's no way to send the GWT-RPC call from other platform than Java without some additionall effort. Please correct me and advise if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have the details on the permitted RemoteService calls, and the objects that are allowed to be serialized, their fields, etc? If so, you should be able to build a request by following the format (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137103/860630 for details on how it works), but for us to help, we need all of those specifics.

Comment: @ColinAlworth: Thanks for the feedback, I'm not maintainer of the server with which I'm trying to communicate with but I'll try to get these information. So getting back to original question - as the GWT server gets request from "webpage" client, there are no restrictions in used programming language which makes such request (as the procedure call syntax is following its own documentation, which you have linked above)?

Comment: I mean... it isnt XML or JSON, but it is a consistent format, there is no reason you can't reimplement it in any other language. Someone had a security tool written in python years ago that used this format to try hacking gwt apps, and I'm sure I've seen a php version years ago... but yeah, just follow the spec, and be sure to ask questions here or the GWT mailing list or IRC if you run into issues.